# How to save multiple rows of HTML table into database

Tags: asp.net-core, html-table, iteration

I have difficulty in saving each record in HTML table rows into database

I want to save a list of records from HTML table into a database.  I have been able to get data for some columns.  However, the first record for a particular column(description) often overrides the remaining rows. My codes so far are below

ViewModel

```
        public SelectList Meetings { get; set; } 

       public string MeetingId { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsPresent { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Members { get; set; }
        public string MemberId { get; set; }
```

View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendance","Attendance",FormMethod.Post))
        {
                 <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                         
                            <input type="date" asp-for="@Model.Date" class="form-control js-datepicker" asp-format="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}">

                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <select type="text" id="meetingType" class="select2 form-control" asp-items="@Model.Meetings" asp-for="@Model.MeetingId" style="width:100%" multiple></select>

                        </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                        
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Members.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@Model.Members[i].Text</td>
                                        
                                        <td><input asp-for="@Model.Description"  id="desc"/></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input type="hidden" class="custom-checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Members[i].Value" />
                                            <label class="a8z-toggle-switch" data-size="sm" data-color="blue" data-text="true" data-style="rounded">
                                                <input asp-for="Members[i].Selected" type="checkbox" id="example_default_1">
                                                <span class="toggle">
                                                    <span class="switch"></span>
                                                </span>
                                             
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                                         
                                
                                }


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddAttendance(AddAttendanceVM addAttendanceVM)
        {
            foreach (var att in addAttendanceVM.Members)
            {
                Attendance addThisAttendance = new()
                {
                    Date = addAttendanceVM.Date,
                    Description = addAttendanceVM.Description,
                    MemberId = att.Value,
                    MeetingId = addAttendanceVM.MeetingId,
                    IsPresent = addAttendanceVM.IsPresent,
                    CreatedBy = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Name").Value,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                };
                xct.Attendances.Add(addThisAttendance); 
            }
                xct.SaveChanges();
            return ViewComponent(nameof(AttendanceLists));
```

[image]

and this is the results in the database
[image]

any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Name for each HTML element should be unique and you use `asp-for="Model.Description"` in a loop. This results into using the first value user provides. Also you use a property from a model, not from the item inside a list

You need more properties than `SelectListItem` carries. Create new class `Member` with `Description` property

```
public class Member
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Change the type of `Members` property

```
public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
```

After this, this line

```
<td><input asp-for="@Model.Description"  id="desc"/></td>
```

Should be changed to

```
<td><input asp-for="@Model.Members[i].Description"  id="desc"/></td>
```

And this line

```
Description = addAttendanceVM.Description,
```

should be changed to

```
Description = att.Description,
```

You will also have to reinitialize your `Members` because the type has changed

Answer (score 0):

You have one meeting with many members, and you are storing one line in the database for each one, so it generates a duplication of the meeting details (like the `Description`).

This is called denormalization, and it should generally be avoided (although it can be used in advanced scenarios to improve [read performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)).

So the general recommendation would be to use at least 2 tables, one for meetings and one for the attendees participating in each meeting, although probably you will also need a table for storing the details of each attendee.

To recap, the tables should look like this:

1. `Meetings` table, with `MeetingId` and other fields like `Description`, `Date`...
2. `Individuals` table, with `IndividualId` and other details like `Name`...
3. `Attendances` table, with only `MeetingId` and `IndividualId`, which should be [Foreign Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) towards the previous tables.

Take a look at this article about implementing this kind of relationship in Entity Framework Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The tables have been designed as you indicated.  The column for the description on the attendance table  is to give more explanation to the especially those who will be marked as absent